# No battery indicator on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, uefi, power-management, indicator, battery

I seem to have lost my battery indicator. Purging and reinstalling `battery-indicator` hasn't helped. I see suggestions of a UEFI update fixing this, but it seems highly unlikely that this can only be fixed like that.

Is there any other way in having a battery indicator again?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No battery indicator in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/487289/no-battery-indicator-in-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: `battery-indicator` doesn't seem to be a valid package on 18.04. You are using GNOME Shell? Did you try [this system-indicator](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/120/system-monitor/)? Includes a battery indicator and much more.